# Finding equations of a tangent space of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus

Consider the function $f:R^3 -> R^2$

$$\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}=f(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}e^{x-y}+y\\sin(x^2-z)\end{pmatrix}.$$
Find the Equations for the tangent space of f at the point $(x,y,z,u,v)=(1,1,1,2,0)$  in the form of ,

$U=Ax+By+Cz+D$

$V=Fx+Gy+Hz+I$

Find the values of $A,B,C,D,F,G,H,I$

What i attempted

Using the equation of the tangent plane, I got

$U_{x}$=$f_{x}$  $x$+$f_{y}$ $y$+$f_{z}$$z$+$u$

$V_{x}$= $V_{x}$$x$+ $V_{y}$ $y$+$V_{z}$$z$+$v$

And working out the value of

$f_{x}$ ,$f_{y}$,$f_{z}$,$V_{x}$,$V_{y}$and$V_{z}$

I got

$U_{x}$=$x+y+2$

and

$V_{x}=2x-z$

However my answer seems to be wrong. Could anyone explain. Thanks

Comment: Um, your tangent space is a line.

Comment: I just changed my answer a little, but i think its still not right. Could u help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to compute the tangent space of the graphic of $f$ at the point $(1,1,1,2,0)$. The graphic of f is just the set $\{(a,b,c,u(a,b,c),v(a,b,c))\}\subseteq \mathbb{R}^{5}$. Observe that $u(1,1,1)=2, v(1,1,1)=0$, so $(1,1,1,2,0)$ belongs to the graphic of $f$.

Using your notation, the vectors of the tangent space are of the form:

$A=x+1, B=y+1, C=z+1$

$U=u_{x}(1,1,1)x+u_{y}(1,1,1)y+u_{z}(1,1,1)z+2$

$ V=v_{x}(1,1,1)x+v_{y}(1,1,1)y+v_{z}(1,1,1)z+0$

The final computation is up to you! (anyway, I think you made a mistake computing $u_y$ which actually is $-e^{x-y}-1$ )

Comment: My final answer is $A=1,B=0,C=0,D=2,F=2,G=0,H=-1,I=0$,am i correct?